# how to use function in one xaml.cs in another xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf

Im wpf application,i have preset.xaml.cs,in that one function is there like adding text to listbox.
But i want to do that function in toolbar.xaml.cs.
How can i refer controls in preset.xaml in toolbar.xaml.cs.

*presetbox is listbox used in preset.xaml
I want to add text for that box from toolbar.xaml.cs.*

Pls help me.Im new to C#.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere else in your project, create a utility class, for example:

```
public static class MyUtils {
    /* your method here */
}
```

Now you should be able to use it from both places as `MyUtils.SomeMethod`; note that it should be a *static* method, so you'll need to pass the textbox in as a parameter.

Comment: public static class MyUtils
{
    public static void AddPresetmenu(ListBox menubox,string pMenu)
    {
        menubox.Items.Add(pMenu);
    }
   
} 


In toolbar.xaml.cs
i coded like
public void Add(string menu)
        {
            MyUtils.AddPresetmenu(menubox, menu);
        }

But it shows error The name 'menubox' does not exist in the current context....
menubox is the control used in trest.xaml.How can i refer this?

Comment: If menubox is definited in xaml, it will need an x:Name attribute in order to be referenced in code.

Comment: Yes in presettabxaml the listbox is as <ListBox x:Name="menubox" Margin="0,5,0,0" >
But still i cannot refer in toolbar.xaml.cs.The same error occurs.

Comment: Are you trying to directly access menubox from toolbar.xaml.cs when it is a property of presettab.xaml?  That won't work - you'll need to access presettab.xaml.cs from within toolbar.xaml.cs which you don't seem to be doing currently.  Does the toolbar.xaml.cs class have an instance of presettab.xaml.cs as a property from which to access menubox?

Comment: No,i dont have any instance of presettab.xaml.cs in toolbar.xaml.cs
I dont know how to do.
Can u send any sample?pls